# How to change a javascript function to target all ID's followed by a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, html5-video

I'm building a site that uses videos contained inside bootstrap modals.

I've got this bit of code that autoplays the video when the user opens the modal and then pauses the video when a user closes it. There are multiple video modals on one page, each one with it's own ID.

Here's the code:

```
$('#smallVideoModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#video1')[0].play();
})
$('#smallVideoModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#video1')[0].pause();
})
```

I was wondering if there was a way that this javascript could be altered in some way to target any modal that starts with an ID of 'smallVideoModal' followed by a numerical number? I don't like the idea of repeating the same piece of javascript for each modal.

Comment: Possible, yes, but *much* better to use a class instead - numeric indexed IDs are usually a pretty bad idea

Comment: The event that your handler received is quite [badly documented](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) or maybe described somewhere without the modal documentation linking to it but I'd bet the value of `this` in your function or the event itself may expose the modal element. So you may get the video eleent with `this.querySelector('video')` or `e.something???..querySelector('video')` depending what the event holds and what is the value of `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.querySelector('video')` on your context (`this` or other)